# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using retain property?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, properties, retain

I have a property in my class called location that uses the nonatomic, retain property. However, I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I assign it to something for the first time. It crashes on the assignment in the code below:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{           
    if(!self.location)
    {
        self.location = 
        [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:newLocation.coordinate.longitude Y:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
```

From what I remember when you use a retain property it automatically releases the current object and retains the new object when you synthesize it. I am thinking that it is throwing this error because I am releasing something that isn't there. But is there a way to get around that or am I seeing it all wrong? Also, it does not throw an error when I use the variable itself, only when self. is used.

Here is my Point2D class information also:

```
@interface Point2D : NSObject {

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) float x, y;

-(id)initWithX:(float)nx Y:(float)ny;

@end

@implementation Point2D
@synthesize x = _x, y = _y;

-(id)init
{
    return [self initWithX:0.00 Y:0.00];
}

-(id)initWithX:(float)nx Y:(float)ny
{
    self = [super init];

    self.x = nx;
    self.y = ny;

    NSLog(@"initWithX");

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: What about `Point2D`'s initializer? Is it proper?

Comment: Note you can send any message (including `release`) to `nil` and nothing will happen. By default, instance variables for newly created objects are zero initialized, so any pointers contain `nil`. Thus you'd only get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS if you'd previously set the `location` instance variable. The value causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS is likely elsewhere. There isn't enough [sample code](http://sscce.org/) to say what's happening. Your best bet is to use XCode's debugger to step into `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` and examine all values.

Comment: Yes, I've synthesized the property using `@synthesize location = _location;`
When I change self.location to _location it works but I need to use it for property so I'm not sure why its throwing an error when I use self. And I am getting an error when I try to set self.location to the Point2D allocation, it enters the if statement fine.

Comment: On an unrelated topic, you should always test the result of `[super init]` and continue initializing only if non-nil.

Answer (score 0):

Check newLocation to make sure that its reference and/or its coordinate property are not returning a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you synthesized the property?I suggest you check that first.And can you check with the debugger if you get the error on  if(!self.location) part or 
self.location = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX...... part?